# PL/SQL Compare Dataset via temp table

Tags: sql, plsql

I've managed to create two temp tables which will be used to compare two datasets, ie we will have two temp tables (dataset1 and dataset2) then specific columns are checked to find similarity / difference.

The main issue I'm having is clearing the temp table completely. I want to have a fresh temp table each time with data specific to my initial select statement.

```
Create global temporary table dataset_1 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
as
select  
 ar.action_sequence as "ACTION_SEQUENCE",
 ar.action_id as "ACTION",
 ar.action_outcome_id as "OUTCOME",
 case when ar.result_action_id is null then 909 else ar.result_action_id end as "RESULT_ACTION"

from 
 ( 
      select
          distinct  ar.action_id ,
           ar.result_action_id, 
           ar.action_outcome_id,
           level action_sequence
      from
           action_result ar
      start with
           ar.action_id = 969726 --&WIP  
      connect by nocycle prior ar.result_action_id = ar.action_id and level < 25
 )  ar ,
 action aca, 
 action acr, 
 outcome oc,
 object_type obj
where
 ar.action_id = aca.action_id
and      
 nvl(ar.result_action_id,ar.action_id ) = acr.action_id
and
 ar.action_outcome_id = oc.outcome_id
and 
 aca.object_type_id = obj.object_type_id

order by 
 ar.action_sequence, aca.action_name;
```

The "datset2" temp table is built the same way as this code. I then run this query to find my intersection points:

```
select action_sequence, result_action from dataset_1 where result_action in (select action from dataset_2);
```

Comment: What kind of problem you have?

Comment: Show us your procedure.

Comment: Remember that in Oracle, temporary tables are created transaction-specific by default. It means that the table content is cleared at every commit. To change this behavior use the ON COMMIT clause of the CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE statement

Comment: Sorry, I can't post images because of my reputation level: here is the code

Comment: BEGIN
truncate table dataset_1;
insert into dataset_1
select  
     ar.action_sequence as "ACTION_SEQUENCE",
     ar.action_id as "ACTION",
     ar.action_outcome_id as "OUTCOME",
     case when ar.result_action_id is null then 909 else ar.result_action_id end as "RESULT_ACTION"

Comment: do you guys have a suggestion how to provide you with the proc?

Comment: You can edit your question and include the code as part of the question. (Note the `edit` button just below the [plsql] tag under the question text). To format text as code you can indent it with four blanks at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE DATASET1';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE DATASET2';

  -- logic to load temp tables with fresh data goes here

  -- logic to compare tables goes here
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Well I'm actually not using a cursor or any other pl/sql logic for data comparison, I'm using the select statement in the edit above to compare data. I do have a version where I used a cursor if you would like to see exactly how it was being done before.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE dataset_1';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE dataset_2';
insert into dataset_1 
select  
 ar.action_sequence as "ACTION_SEQUENCE",
 ar.action_id as "ACTION",
 ar.action_outcome_id as "OUTCOME",
 case when ar.result_action_id is null then 909 else ar.result_action_id end as "RESULT_ACTION"

from 
 ( 
      select
          distinct  ar.action_id ,
           ar.result_action_id, 
           ar.action_outcome_id,
           level action_sequence
      from
           action_result ar
      start with
           ar.action_id = &WIP  
      connect by nocycle prior ar.result_action_id = ar.action_id and level < 25
 )  ar ,
 action aca, 
 action acr, 
 outcome oc,
 object_type obj
where
 ar.action_id = aca.action_id
and      
 nvl(ar.result_action_id,ar.action_id ) = acr.action_id
and
 ar.action_outcome_id = oc.outcome_id
and 
 aca.object_type_id = obj.object_type_id

order by 
 ar.action_sequence, aca.action_name;

---WIP Dataset

insert into dataset_2 
select  
 ar.action_sequence as "ACTION_SEQUENCE",
 ar.action_id as "ACTION",
 ar.action_outcome_id as "OUTCOME",
 case when ar.result_action_id is null then 909 else ar.result_action_id end as "RESULT_ACTION"

from 
 ( 
      select
          distinct  ar.action_id ,
           ar.result_action_id, 
           ar.action_outcome_id,
           level action_sequence
      from
           action_result ar
      start with
           ar.action_id = &Built  
      connect by nocycle prior ar.result_action_id = ar.action_id and level < 25
 )  ar ,
 action aca, 
 action acr, 
 outcome oc,
 object_type obj
where
 ar.action_id = aca.action_id
and      
 nvl(ar.result_action_id,ar.action_id ) = acr.action_id
and
 ar.action_outcome_id = oc.outcome_id
and 
 aca.object_type_id = obj.object_type_id

order by 
 ar.action_sequence, aca.action_name;

END;
```

Thanks for your help ! It's working, here is the final code!